# What SIM covers Thailand, Malaysia, Singapore and Indonesia?

Tags: international-travel, cellphones, thailand

I will be traveling to Thailand, Malaysia, Indonesia and Singapore and will be 
looking for a SIM card for my mobile phone.

Thailand is my first port of entry and basically I need to ask 2 questions here:

1 Which SIM card is the best offering cheap rates plus covering all those countries mentioned above?

2 What documents do I need to buy a SIM card in Thailand?

NB: I prefer 4G or at least 3G speeds.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No local SIM will cover all of your countries cheaply, they will all switch to roaming when you exit the country of purchase.  And roaming is no cheaper in SE Asia than elsewhere.  It is financially better to get a pre-paid SIM in each country as you go.

Not sure of rules in other countries, but in Thailand you need to show your passport when you get a new SIM, as it is required to register the owner of the SIM.  Thailand is mostly 3G data, but some pockets of 4G in bigger cities and some 2G still in rural areas.

Comment: Any particular sim in mind offering cheap rates?

Comment: The rate differences between the three majors in Thailand (AIS,DTAC, True) is negligible.  I use AIS simply because they have the best coverage in remote parts of rural Thailand.  But for cities and places tourists go they are all good.  You will find info desks at Suvarnabhumi Airport as you exit customs, so you can ask them all and pick the package that suits your particular needs.

Comment: I picked dtak sim for tourist. It was 299 bhat for 1 week unlimited internet and calls for Thailand. I'm in krabi now and it was even working fine in phi phi island, also it comes with 4g

Comment: That may be the rule but I have never been asked for id when buying a SIM in Thailand.  On my last trip, I was handed one for free as we got out of the plane (even before immigration).  It was a Happy SIM and came with a little credit.  It was very handy to be able to text local friends immediately on landing.